# Tasks on Thread Building Blocks

Tags: c++, tbb

Here is the example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <tbb/task.h>
#include <tbb/task_group.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

using namespace tbb;

 long fib(long a)
{
  if (a < 2) return 1;

  return fib(a - 1) + fib(a - 2);
}

class PrintTask 
{
public:
    void operator()()
    {
        std::cout << "hi world!: " <<  boost::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;

        fib(50);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{     
    task_group group;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
      group.run(PrintTask());
    }      

    group.wait();

    return(0);
}
```

Here I'm computing a big fibonacci sequence just to simulate non-blocking computation. I was specting that this code would generate more than two threads (my computer is a Core2Duo), but only the first and second tasks are called. This is the spected?

Comment: Are you saying that your function only gets called twice period or that you're only seeing two threads spawned?

Comment: It's not "Thread Building Blocks". It's "Threading Building Blocks". It surprised me when I realised it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is the expected behavior.

TBB is a library designed to parallelize code for PERFORMANCE. It is not designed for asynchronous tasks - the official documentation states that you should use another library, eg pthreads, for such tasks (or boost::thread, in your case).

For maximum performance, it does not make any sense to have more threads than you do cores, as there are some significant overheads involved (not just context switching, but also things like flushing the cache).

EDIT:
You can read about it in the [Tutorial](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/uploads/81/91/Latest%20Open%20Source%20Documentation/Tutorial.pdf). Specifically, in section 1.2 "Benefits" it states

> Intel® Threading Building Blocks targets threading for performance.
>   Most general-purpose threading packages support many different kinds
>   of threading, such as threading for asynchronous events in graphical user
>   interfaces. As a result, general-purpose packages tend to be
>   low-level tools that provide a foundation, not a solution. Instead,
>   Intel® Threading Building Blocks focuses on the particular goal of
>   parallelizing computationally intensive work, delivering
>   higher-level, simpler solutions.

and

> Intel® Threading Building Blocks is compatible with other threading
>   packages. Because the library is not designed to address all threading problems,
>   it can coexist seamlessly with other threading packages.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Dan. I've read the docs but may have slipped this part.

Comment: Glad it helped  The docs have lots of detail thats easy to miss :)

Comment: Since TBB introduced a [task scheduler](http://software.intel.com/en-us/node/467798) for asynchronous execution of tasks, isn't this answer out of date now?

Comment: The task scheduler is what TBB uses to make tasks run, but, at least when I last used TBB (its been a while), it did not support execution in the way the OP wanted. Unless something has significantly changed in the four years since the question was asked, it is still not safe to block inside a TBB task. Taking a quick glance at the link you provided, it looks like this is still true.

Answer (score 1):

Massively multithreading blocking behaviour (std::cout use) is an anti-pattern in multithreading and may result in bad behaviour, because it's the wrong thing to do. In addition, TBB reserves the right to implement group.run() however the hell it likes and spawn whatever threads it likes. If you only have a dual core, and you call with heavy work, why should it spawn more than two threads? The OS and other apps will happily eat remaining background time.

Comment: Sorry, the cout there is just for enumerate the thread id that is calling the task and so doesn't change the point I was making. If I understood what you said, paralellizing the application wouldn't improve the result? I known that in general the 100 tasks would take more time to be executed if made in parallel due to context switch and etcetera, but having to wait to 2 of them end to spawn another task doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @scooterman: cout exhibits numerous threading behaviours, such as blocking. It's not thread safe to just use that way. You're impacting your threading performance substantially by using cout. In addition, there's nothing saying that TBB doesn't spawn two threads and put fifty tasks on each. Also, you really shouldn't mix TBB and boost::thread.

Comment: "you really shouldn't mix TBB and boost::thread" - incorrect. The official TBB documentation states that TBB is designed for performance and that if you wish to use parallel code for other purposes (eg, to run tasks asynchronously), then you should use a traditional threading library. They mention pthreads, but boost::thread is obviously equally valid.

Comment: @Dan: They said that TBB serves one purpose and boost::thread another, not that it was a smart idea to go mixing them in the same application.

Comment: Appendix B of the Tutorial  (conveniently titled "Mixing with other Threading packages") states: Intel® Threading Building Blocks (Intel® TBB) can be mixed with other threading packages. No special effort is required to use any part of Intel® TBB 2.2 with other threading packages." Followed by an example mixing TBB with OpenMP and the other mixing with POSIX threads. Also, in section 11.2: "If you have blocking tasks, it is best to use full-blown threads for those. The task scheduler is designed so that you can safely mix your own threads with Intel® Threading Building Blocks tasks."